Is ${\partial F \over \partial y} \cdot {\partial y \over \partial x}= {\partial F \over \partial x}$ wrong?
For implicit function $F(x,y(x))=0$, to compute $dy \over dx$, we can use the formula,
$$
{dy \over dx} = -{{\partial F \over \partial x} \over {\partial F \over \partial y}}
$$
The formula can be easily found by taking partial derivative with respect to $x$ at both side of the equation,
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\partial F \over \partial x} &= {\partial F \over \partial x}\cdot {\partial x \over \partial x} + {\partial F \over \partial y} \cdot {\partial y \over \partial x}
\\&= {\partial F \over \partial x} + {\partial F \over \partial y} \cdot {dy \over dx}
\\& =0
\end{aligned}
$$
Recall that when computing $dy \over dx$ from a parametric equation like
$$
\begin{cases}
x = f_1(t) \\
y = f_2(t)
\end{cases}
$$
The procedure is like this
$$
{dy \over dx} = {{dy \over dt} \cdot {dt \over dx}}
$$
I'm thinking, you know, this means $dt$ cancels each other, just like a normal number,
$$
{2 \over 3} \cdot {3 \over 5} = {2 \over 5}
$$
So if we wrote $\partial F \over \partial x$ as
$$
{\partial F \over \partial x} = {\partial F \over \partial y} \cdot {\partial y \over \partial x}
$$
then rearrange the equation, we got a different formula,
$$
{\partial y \over \partial x} = {{\partial F \over \partial x} \over {\partial F \over \partial y}}
$$
which has no negative sign.
What I did wrong here? What did I misunderstood?

It looks like you confuse the partial and the total derivative. When you say "the formula can be derived...", it's actually the total derivative, and you should write $\frac{dF}{dx}=...$

Chain rule misunderstood???

You mean, the difference between the parametric situation and multivariate situation is that $F$ is function of $(x, y)$, while $y$ is function of $x$. By writing ${\partial F \over \partial x} = {\partial F \over \partial y} \cdot {\partial y \over \partial x}$, I'm actually ignoring the fact (what we have defined at first, $F(x, y(x))=0$) that $F$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, but treating it as a function of $x$?

It looks like a lot of your confusion comes from the fact that you denote different functions by $F,.$ In the implicit case you differentiate $F(x,y(x))=0,.$ In the other case you differentiate $G(y(x))$ without demanding that this is zero. Another confusion here is to abusively denote $G(y(x))$ by the same letter. Effectively you wrote $G(x)=G(y(x))$ but you should write $H(x)=G(y(x))$ to get $\frac d{dx}H=\frac {dG}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx},.$
